# iOS - Right clicking on a View Controller in a Storyboard opens a menu, what does "manual" under Triggered Segues do?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

iOS - Right clicking on a View Controller in a Storyboard opens a menu, what does "manual" under Triggered Segues do?

How do you use it? I can't seem to find any info in the Class Reference.

PS. The answer might be obvious, but I haven't figured it out. Be gentle!

Comment: if you control drag from a button or uitableviewcell to a viewController the popup menu says Action Segue that's an automatic segue but if you drag from a viewController to a viewController the popup menu says manual segue that means that the menu will create the relationship of the segue and you need to perform that segue manually with performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: I see... that was enlightening. Perfect. Add it as an answer, when you have the time, detailing it a bit and I'll accept it.

Comment: Found this other thread on this exact subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717757/using-segue-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to present a viewController by pressing a UIButton or an UITableViewCell

you nee to hold the key Control and Drag with your mouse from the button or UITableViewCell to the destination viewController, once the destination viewController turns to blue color release the mouse button and a popup should appear with the title Action Segue, select one of the segues and that's it, now you can access to your viewController without any line of code

the UIButton and the UITableViewCell works when the user taps on it but if you have a object that don't have the same behavior of the button like a UIImageView then the Action Segue won't be available

for that kind of situations you need to make a Manual Segue

inside storyboard hold the key Control and Drag with your mouse from the viewController to the destination viewController, once the destination viewController turns to blue color release the mouse button and a popup should appear with the title Manual Segue, select one of the segues and now you should see a line with an arrow and a circle in the middle, click the circle and open the Attributes Inspector and add an identifier.

At this point you are done with storyboard now you need to add some code to your view controller to trigger that segue.

let's say that you have a UIImageView then you need to do the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImageView *overflow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"]];
    overflow.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 150, 150);
    overflow.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    [self.view addSubview:overflow];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [overflow addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_identifier" sender:self];
}
```

Now every time you want to present the viewController just tap the image

Once the destinationViewController is presented you can dismiss it with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

When you right click on the viewController and the menu pops up look below Triggered Segues if manual is empty means that you haven't set a manual segue

Good Luck!